# All Unity 3D games result in "Force Close"

Tags: cyanogenmod, force-close, huawei-u8160

I have a Huawei u8160 (A.K.A Vodafone 858 Smart) running CyanogenMod 7.2 Madteam ported.

All apps that use unity3d force close on their startup although they are compatible.

So I wanted to know if I should install something to make it work or any thing else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because **they're not compatible.**
Unity requires devices with ARMv7 instruction set, your phone only supports v6.

I'm sorry but there's nothing that you can do other than buy a new handset if you want to play cutting edge games.

See [this](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2874&view=1&c=vodafone_858_smart_huawei_u8160) for the detailed specifications of your phone.

Comment: can you recommend another gaming sdk for ARMv6? and also corona SDK games crash is that is the same reason?

Comment: Yeah it's the same with Corona. I'm not aware of any other SDK of this kind besides these two. Older versions of Corona support ARMv6 though, but that version is only available for subscribers and no games are released with it.

Answer (score 1):

Unity games work on arm v6 with VFP, most cell phones sold after 2011 that have qualcomms and arm v6 work with unity games, however, this is an issue with cyanogenmod as of 8-21-2012, but if you remove parts of your game and load a blank level, you'll see it works, so its just a missing piece, no clue if they will fix it or find it.

Comment: do you have a link to that known issue for CM?

Comment: Do you have a source?